# How to keep the plus sign when importing CSV file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that I need to import into my project. The CSV file is similar to this:

| lower | upper | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -inf | 2.1 | #00AEEF |
| 2.1 | +inf | #ED1C24 |

or

```
lower,upper,color
-inf,2.1,#00AEEF
2.1,+inf,#ED1C24
```

And my code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('rules.csv')

for i, r in df.iterrows():
    low = r['lower']
    high = r['upper']

    print(low,high)
```

The output was:

```
-inf 2.1
2.1 inf
```

My question is why was it `inf` and not `+inf` just like the data? And is there a way to modify the importing process?

Comment: Please over the raw text (including header and separators, etc) of your CSV file not a markdown table.

Comment: What do you want to do with the values? `inf` is the representation of the **float** `inf`, that is not a string and has a special meaning (for example `-1*inf` gives `-inf`), so you should probably leave it as it it

Comment: Why do you want special treament for `inf`? Other positive numbers aren't printed with a `+` prefix, too. If you want `+inf` you should also want `+2.1`, no?

Comment: I want to convert it into a string so that i can use it in a text like
map="-inf:2.1=#8000AEEF;2.1:+inf=#80ED1C24;"

Comment: Why does that require a + prefix?

Comment: I'm coding for Niagara platform which does not recognize inf, only -inf or +inf

Comment: would it be an option to read in all data as strings, instead of numeric values?

Comment: thank you 
I have just thought of that and it solved it
honestly i thought that +inf would be considered as a string not a positive number